# HTML5, Javascript: Audio ended not working

Tags: javascript, html, audio, browser

Hey guys i build a AudioQueue for my game and somehow it doenst work, code:

```
handleAction: function ( src )
    {
        var oAudio = document.getElementById('voice');

        if(this.lastSoundPlayed == undefined || src != this.lastSoundPlayed.src) // checks if there is an actual new sound incoming.
        {
            var self  = this;
            oAudio.src = src; //sets the source
            oAudio.load();
            oAudio.onloadeddata  = oAudio.play(); // when loaded play the sound
            oAudio.onended = self.soundDone( self, oAudio ); //when the sound is finished fire the soundDone function
        }
    }
```

the soundDone() function:

```
soundDone: function( self , oAudio )
    {
        console.log("Finished"); //logs that the sound is finished
        self.lastSoundPlayed = oAudio; //sets the lastSoundPlayed
        self.sendNotification(self.SC_ACTION_COMPLETE); //fires off a notification that the sound is finished (im using pureMVC)
    }
```

well the actual problem is that he thinks that the sounds is instant finished. ive logged the duration of my sounds and there all NaN? i've checked that with console.log(oAudio.duration). i dont know why this is happening. i also have background music wich i play the same way as these sounds and with the background music is nothing wrong.

Someone can help me?

EDIT: this is the audio tag for my audio:

```
<audio id="voice" src="mySound.mp3" controls preload="auto" ></audio>
```

Comment: the oAudio.duration return NaN. but i think it isnt fully loaded yet thats why... thank anyway!

Comment: Could you add the code that returns NaN? I can't find oAudio.duration anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it couple of weeks ago, the sounds wasnt fully loaded when i called it.